# yo @microsoft/sharepoint fails on TypeError: lookups.flatMap is not a function

Tags: yeoman, spfx

After installation of Node v10.16.1 and installation of gulp and yo (Everything looks alright !) it fails on command `yo @microsoft/sharepoint`  with TypeError: lookups.flatMap is not a function

```
C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\resolver.js:70
    filePatterns: lookups.flatMap(prefix => [`${prefix}/*/index.ts`, `${prefix}/*/index.js`]),
                          ^

TypeError: lookups.flatMap is not a function
    at Environment.resolver.lookup (C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\resolver.js:70:27)
    at init (C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js:130:7)
    at pre (C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js:89:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js:219:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
```

I am a beginner ! Few days ago it worked , then I installed nvm (following a microsoft instruction to swap node v8 to node v10) and then problems started and i uninstalled nvm, node v8 and v10 en reinstalled node v10. The TypeError returns. Perhaps something to do with path ?
Any idea ? thx

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I resolved this by downgrading my gulp and yeoman versions.

First checked to see what I had installed:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

Output:

```
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0
+-- gulp@4.0.2
+-- npm@6.14.12
+-- windows-build-tools@5.2.2
-- yo@4.0.0
```

So I uninstalled both gulp and yeoman:

```
npm uninstall -g gulp
npm uninstall -g yo
```

Then installed older versions:

```
npm install -g gulp@3.9.1
npm install -g yo@3.1.0
```

Then was able to generate the SharePoint framework project successfully after running:

```
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
```

Once it completed, I was able to run the following from inside the SharePoint framework project directory to launch the local workbench:

```
gulp serve
```

Note: If if not already done so once, you need to generate a development certificate inside the SharePoint framework project directory:

```
gulp trust-dev-cert
```

Answer (score 11):

I believe you should **upgrade node.js to v14**, as stated in [Microsoft official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment):

> Install the latest version of Node.js LTS v14.
> This version is the currently recommended version of Node.js to use with the SharePoint Framework

Node v10 is [EOL in few days](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/) (tomorrow, in fact), so it is unsafe to use it.

I faced the same issue today while scaffolding a new webpart, and I solved by upgrading node from v10 to v14.

Another suggestion is to avoid installing global npm packages if you are going to use it just once (for scaffolding, for example); I usually use [npx](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx/) to download on the fly *yo* and the *microsoft generator*, so I always use the latest available versions:

```
$ npx -p yo -p @microsoft/generator-sharepoint -c "yo @microsoft/sharepoint"
```

Hope this can help, bye!

Comment: don't know why, my first row containing "Hi @thb" is deleted when I try to post my answer (?); if I write 'welcome' instead of 'Hi', all is fine.

Comment: After upgrading to node 14, issue got resolved. Also installed gulp@3.9.1 and yo@3.1.0

Comment: If you upgrade to Node 14, be careful if you rely on @pnp/generator-spfx and develop your webparts in anything other than React.

Answer (score 1):

First try to uninstall both gulp and yeoman:
to uninstall run these commands-->

```
npm uninstall -g gulp
npm uninstall -g yo
```

Then installed older versions:
to install run these commands-->

```
npm install -g gulp@3.9.1
npm install -g yo@3.1.0
```

Then was able to generate the SharePoint framework project successfully after running:

```
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
```

Answer (score 1):

Check version list if same or not:

```
npm list -g --depth=0

+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0
+-- gulp@3.9.1
+-- gulp-cli@2.3.0
+-- yarn@1.22.17
+-- yo@3.1.0
```

Run below commands to uninstall:

```
npm uninstall -g gulp
npm uninstall -g yo
```

Run below commands:

```
npm install -g gulp@3.9.1
npm install -g yo@3.1.0
npm uninstall -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
```

Then install a previous version:

```
npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0
```