# VS Code extension TypeError: lookups.flatMap is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, yo

I am trying to create a VS code extension following this tutorial:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

I've installed yo and generator code using

`https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension`

When i run `yo code`, I keep getting this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/resolver.js:69
    filePatterns: lookups.flatMap(prefix => [`${prefix}/*/index.ts`, `${prefix}/*/index.js`, `${prefix}/*/index.cjs`, `${prefix}/*/index.mjs`]),
                          ^

TypeError: lookups.flatMap is not a function
    at Environment.resolver.lookup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/resolver.js:69:27)
    at init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:130:7)
    at pre (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:89:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:219:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Why is this happening and is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I think you need to use `babel`

Comment: @captain-yossarian What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that lookups is either not an array or your js version does not support this method

Comment: @captain-yossarian Which version of javascript should I be using for this?

Comment: are you using node.js?

Comment: @captain-yossarian yes. node v10.19.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239201/discussion-between-arjunlal-m-a-and-captain-yossarian).

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is (kind of) a similar issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67252829/9986280).
I would suggest, u follow the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67254654/9986280). :)